# How do I refund a single item and shipping proportional to the item refunded?

Tags: shopify, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I have an order with 3 different line items.

I need to refund 1 of those items (which is heavy and adds to the shipping price). Without this item I can reduce the price of the shipping by X.

How can I refund X? How can I automatically calculate how much I have to refund from the shipping? Does Shopify do that automatically?

The [documentation example](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/refund#calculate) doesn't go too much in detail, it only states that you can send `amount`, but not how to figure out what the `amount` is.

Answer (score 0):

Just refund the price of the item itself. Refunding a percentage of shipping? Who does that. I have never experience any e-commerce where you get shipping refunds. If I pay for shipping, I paid for something non-refundable.

Comment: In this case we would want to refund 1 item and send the other 2 (you can safely assume that it has not been shipped at this point). We don't want to refund the entire order. Does it make sense?

Comment: So be complicated. You have the origin, destination and remaining line items in your data. Make a single request for a new shipping rate. Subtract the new rate from the one you charged, and add the difference to the refund.